# Mule: Http->xml

Tags: java, xml, mule, mule-studio

Mule version: 3,5 (Actually, mule studio)

I'm new at using mule and can't seem to figure out how to do the following properly:

**Want to achieve:**
Send data from a html form to mule which then splits the payload and sends one part to one java program and the other to another.

Html form:

```
<form method="GET" action="http://localhost:8081">
 <input type="text" name="name"/>
 <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This points to localhost and the port which is set in MuleStudio.

**Real Question:**
What could I use to transform the data from the inbound http to xml?

**Side Question:**
I can send the whole payload to one javaprogram. (first a POJO and then to the actual program. - is this the right way or can I send it to the program and skipping the POJO?)

Comment: Is the XML format defined by a schema?

Comment: No, not yet, but I could quickly do that.

Comment: OK. Can you please define "Java program"? Do you mean calling a method available in the same JVM, calling a remote Java application over TCP/HTTP/RMI... or starting an external Java program from the command line?

Comment: Calling a remote Java application over RMI.

Comment: Do you have ready made client classes for call the remote app? Or do you intend to use the RMI transport http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/RMI+Transport+Reference ?

Comment: I was thinking about making a client class, but will look into RMI transporting. So far I'm more stuck at transforming the data from the form to xml.

Answer (score 1):

Since your main concern is about transformation, let's only address it.

- If you're using the Enterprise Edition, you can use DataMapper to generate the XML you need. Creating a schema representing the target XML would help a lot.
- Otherwise, if you're using the Community Edition, you can use different options:

  - A Groovy component using the excellent MarkupBuilder to generate the target XML right from the inbound message payload,
  - A chain of standard transformers that first transform the submitted data to a generic XML form (`object-to-xml-transformer`) then transform it to the desired form (`xslt-transformer`).

I'm sure there are other options, but these should get you going :)